# Does a sequence of vectors whose norms converge to zero necessarily converge to the zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be an $N$-dimensional normed vector space, and let $(v_n)$ be a sequence of vectors such that $\lim (\left \| v_n \right \|)=0$. Given some basis $\{e^1,e^2,..., e^N \}$, we can write each $v_n$ as $a_1^{(n)}e^1+a_2^{(n)}e^2 +\dots  + a_N^{(n)}e^N$.

Is it necessarily true that for each fixed $k \in \{1, 2, \dots, N\}$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_k^{(n)}=0$ ? If so, how can we prove this using only the axioms for a generic norm?

Comment: Yes, since one has the result that all norms are equivalent.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: That's kind of a heavy hammer, though.  I wonder if there is a proof of this that doesn't need the Heine-Borel theorem?

Comment: The questions in the title and in the body are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought the simplest way is that $\lvert\lvert v_n \rvert\rvert \rightarrow 0$ is the same as $\lvert \lvert v_n - 0 \rvert\rvert \rightarrow 0$, i.e. $v_n \rightarrow 0$.

EDIT 1: Let $v_n = a_1^ne_1 + \cdots + a_N^ne_N$. Then $\lvert\lvert v_n \rvert\rvert = \lvert\lvert \sum_{i=1}^N a_i^n e_i \rvert\rvert \leq \sum_{i=1}^N \lvert \lvert a_i^ne_i \rvert\rvert$ by the triangle inequality. Thus if $v_n \rightarrow 0$ component-wise, i.e. $a_i^n \rightarrow 0$, then $\lvert\lvert a_i^ne_i \rvert\rvert = \lvert a_i^n \rvert \lvert\lvert e_i \rvert\rvert \rightarrow 0$ and hence $\lvert \lvert v_n \rvert \rvert \rightarrow 0$, i.e. $v_n \rightarrow 0$ in norm.

On the other hand, if $v_n \rightarrow 0$ in norm but not all $a_i^n \rightarrow 0$, let $v = a_1e_1 + \cdots + a_Ne_N$ where $a_i = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_i^n$. Then $v$ is nonzero, since $(e_j)_{j=1}^N$ is a basis and at least one $a_i \neq 0$, and $\lvert \lvert v_n - v \rvert \rvert \leq \sum_{i=1}^N \lvert \lvert (a_i^n - a_i)e_i \rvert \rvert \rightarrow 0$ so $v_n \rightarrow v$, a contradiction since by continuity of the norm, $\lvert \lvert v_n \rvert \rvert \rightarrow \lvert \lvert v \rvert \rvert \neq 0$.

EDIT 2: The above assumes the limit exists, which may not be true. I'm not sure how to show the limit exists.

Comment: Hm, is $v_n \to x$ defined to mean $||v_n-x|| \to 0$ or that the components of $v_n$ approach the components of $x$ in some basis?

Comment: I guess what I'm really looking for is a proof that these two definitions facts are equivalent.

Comment: If you're wondering if convergence in norm is equivalent to component-wise convergence in finite dimensional normed vector spaces, then I think I've edited accordingly. As for your first question, $v_n \rightarrow x$ in a normed vector space is taken to mean $\lvert\lvert v_n - x \rvert\rvert \rightarrow 0$, since the norm induces the metric.

Comment: Riley's proof is wrong. One has to prove that $\lim a_i^{n}$ exists and is $0$. You cannot assume that the limit exists and show that the limit must be $0$.

Comment: Hmm yes, I do have issues showing the limit exists. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: I'm going to go with this answer because even though it's partly incomplete, it's nice and simple and actually good enough for my purposes. I am going through a proof involving a sequence of vectors whose components definitely have well-defined but nonzero limits, and just wanted to show that it couldn't be approaching the zero vector, so this suffices. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**To answer the question in the title (which is a little bit different than the question in the body of the OP):**

Let's get back to the definitions! The benefit is that we don't need component, and the answer would work in infinite dimension.

In a normed vector space, we have a natural distance between vectors $v$ and $w$ given by $||v-w||$. Therefore, convergence in a normed vector space is defined as the convergence in the metric space induced by the norm, that

> **Definition $1$**: Let $v_n$ be a sequence of vectors in a normed space $(V,||\cdot||)$. We say that $v_n$ converges to a vector $v$ in $V$ if, for any $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that, if $n\geqslant N$, then $||v_n-v||<\varepsilon$.

In plain English, we can make $v_n$ as close as we want to $v$ (that is, we can make the distance between $v_n$ and $v$ as small as we want), provided that $n$ is large enough.

Now, consider the sequence $x_n=||v_n||$ of the norms of the vectors $v_n$. That's a sequence of **real numbers** so its convergence is defined by the "classic" (Calculus 1 or 2 course) convergence of sequences:

> **Definition $2$**: Let $x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. We say that $x_n$ converges to a real number $\ell$ if, for any $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that, if $n\geqslant N$, then $|x_n-\ell|<\varepsilon$.

This time, we are using the distance between real numbers, that is the absolute value of their difference.

We are finally in position to answer the question in the title (and a little bit more):

> **Theorem**: Let $v_n$ be a sequence of vectors in a normed space $(V,||\cdot||)$. Then $v_n$ converges to the zero vector $0$ if and only if its sequence of norms $x_n=||v_n||$ converges to $0$.

The proof is essentially that $|x_n-0|=|x_n|=|\;||v_n||\;|=||v_n||=||v_n-0||$.
Indeed, assume that $x_n=||v_n||$ converges to $0$. We will show that $v_n$ has to converge to the zero vector. For, let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $x_n$ converges to $0$, there exists $N$ in $\mathbb N$ such that, if $n\geqslant N_1$, we have $|x_n|<\varepsilon$. Therefore, if $n\geqslant N$, we have also $||v_n||<\epsilon$, so the claim is proved.

It should be obvious that the proof of the converse is almost identical. I think that a source of confusion is that it seems "too easy".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that uses no theorem on normed linear spaces: Let $x_n=(a_1^{(n)},a_2^{(n)},\cdots,a_N^{(n)})$ and $r_n$ be its (usual) norm in $\mathbb R^{N}$. If $\{r_n\}$ is unbounded there is a subsequence $\{r_n'\}$ that tends to $\infty$. Now $\frac {v_n'} {r_n'} \to 0$ and we get unit vectors $(b_1^{(n')},b_2^{(n')},\cdots,b_N^{(n')})$ (obtained by normalizing $(a_1^{(n')},a_2^{(n')},\cdots,a_N^{(n')})$) such that $\sum b_i^{(n')}e_i \to 0$. But any sequence of unit vectors in $\mathbb R^{N}$ has  a subsequence which tends to  unit vector. We end up with $\sum c_i e_i=0$ where $(c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n)$ is a unit vector contradicting linear independence of $e_i$'s. Hence $\{r_n\}$ is bounded. Now extract a convergent subsequence and take the limit in the equation $v_n=\sum a_1^{(n)}e_i$ to see that the limit of the subsquence must be $(0,0,\cdots,0)$. Now you can apply this argument to subsequences of $(a_1^{(n)},a_2^{(n)},\cdots,a_N^{(n)})$ to conclude that every subsequence of this has  a further subsequence converging to the zero vector. Hence $a_i^{(n)} \to 0$ for each $i$.

PS This approach can be used prove many of the basic theorem about finite dimensional normed linear spaces from scratch. Unfortunately it is not seen in text books. By this approach you can prove that finite dimensional subspaces are closed, that linear maps on finite dimensional spaces are continuous and all norms on finite dimensional spaces are equivalent.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the difference between $v_n$ and $x_n$, and what exactly it means that $v_n/r_n \to 0$. Should that $v_n$ be a norm, and should that $r_n$ be primed? Also, does this generalize to all norms, not just the standard $\mathbb{R}^N$ norm?

Comment: I am working simultaneously in two spaces: the given normed linear space and the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^{N}$. $x_n$ is a vector in the latter and $r_n$ is its norm, which is a positive number. I am proving the result for any any norm on any vector space but the proof utilizes Euclidean norm as a tool. The prime is only a notation for a subsequence (just to avoid typing subscripts).

Comment: Does $v_n/r_n \to 0$ mean that the norms of $v_n/r_n$ approach zero, or that all the components of these vectors in some particular basis approach zero? I'm trying not to assume these are identical statements.

Comment: A sequence of vectors in a normed linear sapce converges to $0$ off their norms converge to $0$. It is already given that $\|v_n\| \to 0$ so if $r_n '\to \infty$ then certainly $\|\frac {v_n'} {r_n'}\|$ also tends to $0$.

Answer (score -1):

Going off this question, is it possible for there to be an infinite sequence whose L2 norm goes to zero as N goes to infinity, but for every t in it's duration, the signal at t does NOT tend to zero?

Comment: I'd recommend posting a new question for this, and linking to this post as background.